# AngularJS When and Otherwise with UI Rout

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new angular student.
I have a problem with my routes of UI Route.

here is my code:

```
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/GRN', '/GRN/Produtos')
    .when('/Executivo', "Executivo/Produtos")
    .otherwise("/NotFound")
```

i want to do this:

```
When -> /GRN/SOME_WRONG_LINK -> go to /GRN/Produtos
When -> /Executivo/SOME_WRONG_LINK -> go to /Executivo/Produtos
When -> /SOME_WRONG_LINK -> Go to NotFound
```

Basically i want if the user start putting right URL (in this case GRN or Executivo), he goes to one main page of this link, and no to "NotFound", because he starts with a right link.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

**Using `$routeProvider`**:

Since you used `$routeProvider` in your question,

you can use,

```
.c.run(function($rootScope,$location,$state) {

$rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e,toState,toParams,fromState,fromParams) {

    if( $location.path().search('GRN') > -1)
    {
        $state.go('GRN_Produtos');
        event.preventDefault();     
    }

    if( $location.path().search('Executivo') > -1)
        $state.go('Executivo_Produtos');
        event.preventDefault();     
    }

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

});
```

});onfig(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider

```
  .when('/GRN',{redirectTo:'/GRN/Produtos'})  

  .when('/Executivo',{redirectTo:'/Executivo/Produtos'})  

  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/NotFound'}); 
}])
```

**redirectTo**:

{(string|Function)} => value to update $location path with and trigger route redirection.

[Here is the reference od redirectTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

**Using `$stateProvider`**:

Assuming your states as below,

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('GRN_Produtos', {
            url: '/GRN/Produtos',
            templateUrl: '',
            controller: ''
        })
        .state('Executivo_Produtos', {
            url: '/Executivo/Produtos',
            templateUrl: '',
            controller: ''
        })
      .state('otherwise', {
            url: '/notfound',
       });

    }])
```

Now you can redirect in the run block,

```
  .run(function($rootScope,$location,$state) {

    $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e,toState,toParams,fromState,fromParams) {

        if( $location.path().search('GRN') > -1)
        {
            $state.go('GRN_Produtos');
            event.preventDefault();     
        }

        else if( $location.path().search('Executivo') > -1)
            $state.go('Executivo_Produtos');
            event.preventDefault();     
        }
        else
        {
            $state.go('otherwise');
            event.preventDefault();     
        }


    });    
});
```

Comment: Hi Sravan, thanks a lot for aswer.
But i'm using UI-SREF, $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider. this is for NG-View. There is a way to URL Router? Thanks!

Comment: do you have states configured for the routes?

Comment: Yes, i have already states done.
my actual .run is:

.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
        });

when i substitute for yours code, it didnt work and there is a error in console that $urlRouterProvider is not defined.

=(

Comment: your config file should contain `$urlRouterProvider`

Comment: `app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)`

Comment: When i remove this "$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");", it works well, but i want when the user starts link with "www.somelink.com/GRN/Wrong_Link", he goes to "www.somelink.com/GRN/Produtos", and now it is going to www.somelink.com/NotFound. i just want he goes to /NotFound when he put www.somelink.com/Wrong_Link

do you understand me? haha Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have edited the answer for what you want if  wrong or some other url is typed or entered. You can achieve same using **$stateChangeStart** but simplest was the above one

Comment: @Vitor, so if the url contain GRN, you need to redirect to `www.somelink.com/GRN/Produtos` and if the url contain Executivo, you need to redirect to `www.somelink.com/Executivo/Produtos` right?