# AngularJS - $stateProvider when user put wrong URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm new angularjs student.
I'm using state provider in my project, i don't want to change this. Because the code is done.

Here is my code:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {



$urlRouterProvider 
 .when('/SecondMain', '/SecondMain/OtherPageOne')
 .when('/Main', '/Main/PageOne')
 .otherwise("/notfound")

$stateProvider
    .state('Main', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/Main",
        templateUrl: "/templates/Common/Main.html"
    })
    .state('SecondMain', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/SecondMain",
        templateUrl: "/templates/Common/SecondMain.html"
    })
    .state('notfound', {
        url: "/NotFound",
        templateUrl: "/templates/Common/NotFound.html"
    })
    .state('Main.PageOne', {
        url: "/Main/PageOne",
        templateUrl: "/templates/Main/PageOne.html"
    })
    .state('Main.PageTwo', {
        url: "/Main/PageTwo",
        templateUrl: "/templates/Main/PageTwo.html"
    })
    .state('SecondMain.OtherPageOne', {
        url: "/SecondMain/PageOne",
        templateUrl: "/templates/SecondMain/OtherPageOne.html"
    })
    .state('SecondMain.OtherPageTwo', {
        url: "/SecondMain/PageTwo",
        templateUrl: "/templates/SecondMain/OtherPageTwo.html"
    })
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .config(config)
    .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
}
```

I want a logic like this: If the user put:

> /Main/PageThree

This page does not exist, but the user start URL with

> /Main

so that he need to go to -> /Main/PageOne

if the user put:

> /Ma/PageOne

**/Ma** does not exist, the user starts URL totally wrong, so that he goes to -> /Notfound Basically if the user put /Main/WRONG_LINK, he go to /Main/PageOne . And if he does not start with /Main, he go to NotFound.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Where is otherwise??

Comment: $urlRouterProvider .when('/Main', '/Main/PageOne') .otherwise("/notfound") I already have otherwise.

Comment: If that is there please update with the post.

Comment: Here you are. Updated! =)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this configuration

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/NotFound');
```

Just add this line if no matching route is found then it will redirect you to the /NotFound url

Comment: $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/Main', '/Main/PageOne')
    .otherwise("/notfound")

I already have otherwise. But i want a logic like i said:

If the user put:

**/Main/PageThree** < This page does not exist, but the user start URL with /Main, so that he need to go to -> /Main/PageOne

/Ma/PageOne < /Ma does not exist, the user starts URL totally wrong, so that he goes to -> /Notfound

Basically if the user put **/Main/WRONG_LINK**, he go to /Main/PageOne . And if he does not start with /Main, he go to NotFound.

Thanks for aswer!

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491412/2019247).**

First of all, you will have to make the `Main` state non-abstract, so that it can be visited. Then, you can write config related to where you want to redirect (for example, I've used `redirectTo` with the state):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('Main', {
      redirectTo: "Main.PageOne",
      url: "/Main",
      templateUrl: "/templates/Common/Main.html"
  })
// ... Rest of code
```

So, whenever the URL is changed to `/Main`, this state will get activated. The second config will be to create a listener for `$stateChangeStart` event as follows:

```
angular
  .module('inspinia')
  .config(config)
  .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params, { location: 'replace' })
      }
    });
  });
```

Now, if a URL like `/Ma/*` is hit, it automatically be redirected to `/NotFound`. And if a URL like `/Main` is hit, it will redirect to `/Main/PageOne`.

You can follow up on further discussion [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491079/redirect-a-state-to-default-substate-with-ui-router-in-angularjs) for any kind of troubleshooting.

Comment: actually i need a state abstract. Because i have 2 abstract states. for this question i put only one abstract state. i have already question something like this before. i think the other user understood better my question. take a look please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864366/angularjs-when-and-otherwise-with-ui-rout

Answer (score 0):

Clearly read the statements below

Why are you using this line?

```
when('/Main', '/Main/PageOne')
```

For your redirection problem, have a look at the below state

```
.state('Main', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/Main",
    templateUrl: "/templates/Common/Main.html"
})
```

**abstract: true** ==> This denotes that this particular state is an **abstract** which can never be activated without its child.

**SOURCE:** ui-router js code. Refer the below snippet

Since you have this **main** state as abstract, you are redirected to the otherwise.

[image]

Hope this

Comment: Hi! I have .when because i have 2 abstract states. I will update my question. I made this way because i thought it was more easier to understand. UPDATED.

Comment: can you connect with me in fb?

Comment: Take a look now if you can help me, please =)

Comment: Please don't add your questions and keep going. If u want tell me I'll Clearly explain with ur full code in view in team viewer

Comment: Oh Really? i would like that so much! what is your facebook? i can show you tomorrow!

Comment: aravind2109 see u der